# Safely write to files with conflicting names in an NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

This is probably a pretty basic `NSOperationQueue` question, but maybe it will help some other people out who are just learning this as well.

I'm trying to copy multiple .plist files from the `~/Documents` directory to the `~/Library` directory in an iOS application. I want to use `NSOperations` to copy each file to speed this up and take the import process off the main thread.

In my implementation, it's possible that two files of the same name could be copied into the same place. What I'd like to do is make sure that one of the operations changes the filename to one that doesn't exist before it writes the file. What would be the most straight-forward way to go about this?

Thanks,

-c

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to do. It's not at all clear. Are you reading, writing, or both?

Comment: I'm writing files. I just need to make sure that one thread doesn't start writing over a file that is currently being written to by another thread. Just updated my question to hopefully make this a bit more clear.

Comment: Why don't you keep a array for holding file names. A threads should add the file's name to that array before it starts to write. Once it completed successfully the thread should remove that particular file name from the array. At any time a thread wants to write a file it should check that the file name is exists in the array.

Comment: I was thinking of a solution along that line. I guess that means I'd have to make sure my read/writes to the array are in a @synchronized block right?

Comment: How are the name collisions happening? The files already have unique names in Documents, don't they?